# Regarding templates for struct in C++

Tags: c++, struct

Method 1:

```
 template <class T>
 struct node{
      T data;
      struct node *next;
 };
```

Method 2:

```
 template <class T>
 struct node{
      T data;
      struct node<T> *next; // different from above
 };
```

Both of them compiles and runs correctly for a linked list.

Isn't there a difference? If not, why?

Comment: there is no difference. You can even omit `struct` and say `node* next;`. That would be the "normal" way.

Comment: rest anywhere in code I am not allowed to use the code struct node only struct node<T> works

Comment: @codeymodey: Inside of a `node<T>`, you can simply write `node`, and it will assume the current `<T>`.  Outside of a `node<T>`, you must always specify the `<T>` because the compiler doesn't have enough context to deduce it.

Comment: Correct, this only works inside the class declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference.

The reason that this is so is because, for convenience, within a templated class/struct, the naked name of that class/struct refers to the current template instantiation.

This feature becomes really handy if you have, say, six templated arguments that themselves have templated arguments, and you just want to declare a pointer :-)